# How to get continuous output from C in PHP

Tags: php, c

I am having difficulties to get continuous outputs from C in PHP.

So I have made a simple example to explain what I am trying to achieve.

Given test.c is my C program that displays continuous outputs

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int c, char **v)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("%d\n",counter);
        counter++;
        sleep(2+rand()%4);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then compiled with

```
gcc -o test test.c
```

C program is run in test.sh below:

test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

./test
```

Then make test.sh executable with:

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

Now I want to get the continuous ouptut from C in test.php

test.php

```
<?php

    shell_exec("./test.sh");
?>
```

when run on command line client with below command nothing shows.

```
php test.php
```

Please how can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

after `printf`.

**Edit**:

And use `passthru` instead of `shell_exec`.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
    system("./test.sh");
?>
```

or even directly:

```
<?php
    system("./test")
?>
```